# Dynamic IFrame Content from stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, payment-gateway

I'm currently trying to implement something called 3d secure into our checkout system-
[Implementing DataCash 3DSecure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239760/implementing-datacash-3dsecure-in-c)

I've got most of the way there with it, however now, i'm having trouble creating an iFrame with the correct content in.

Basically, the user enters their credit card details, presses the "order" button and the page contacts the payment gateway (DataCash in our case)
If the card requires 3d secure authentication, a pareq (long message) is returned with a bunch of other stuff.

I've generated the page required, using this code:
[HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse Base 64 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265612/httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse-base-64-problem)

However, i need to implement this into an iFrame.

Here's how the documentation suggest doing it, but i cant seem to get it....

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Please Authenticate</title>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoadEvent();">
    <form name="downloadForm" action="https://mybank.com/vbyv/verify" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="AAABBBBCCCCHHHHHH=">
      <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="https:// www. MyWidgits.Com/next.cgi">
      <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="200304012012a">
    </form>

    <script language="Javascript"> <!--        function OnLoadEvent() { document.downloadForm.target = "ACSframe"; document.downloadForm.submit(); } //--> </script>

    <!-- MERCHANT TO FILL IN THEIR OWN BRANDING HERE -->
    <iframe src="blank.htm" name="ACSframe" width="390" height="450" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
    <!-- MERCHANT TO FILL IN THEIR OWN BRANDING HERE -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you changing your source when you are updating?

Comment: sorry, im not sure i understand.... changing what source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this as follows:

http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/implementing-datacash-3d-secure-with-asp-net/